# Formik and Yup : TypeError: Cannot read property 'object' of undefined

Tags: reactjs, formik, yup

I am new to React and was trying out formik with yup for the validation. I am currently getting the error below:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'object' of undefined

with this code:

```
validationSchema: Yup.object().shape({
  firstName: Yup.string().required()
}),
```

I am using all the latest versions of formik,react and yup. The versions are

> "yup": "^0.25.1" "formik": "^0.11.11", "react": "^16.4.0",
>   "react-dom": "^16.4.0",

Could some one help me to resolve this issue?

It is replicated here
https://codesandbox.io/s/lrowpj8pq7

Thanks!

Comment: provide code where you are getting the error

Comment: I have added sample code

Comment: Shawn, please change the correct answer.

Answer (score 133, accepted):

The correct answer is not to downgrade, but to change how you import it.

Try `import * as Yup from 'yup'` instead of `import Yup from 'yup'`.

```
// wrong
import Yup from 'yup';

// correct
import * as Yup from 'yup';
```

Here is your example working: https://codesandbox.io/s/xlnw2x0kk4.

Comment: It was breaking for me and this answer helped without downgrading! Thanks.

Comment: @Panos Bechlivanos just curios. why this matters?

Comment: @Ezeewei it matters because in javascript there are many variations in how you will export your modules eg.  in this example they changed how they exported their modules from exporting a big object that contained every function, to exporting every function separately as a named export.

Comment: import * as Yup from 'yup'; 

using this still getting same error ^0.27.0

Comment: This did not work on on march 2021. Maybe it is not valid on newer version. Need new solution.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and then I realised I was using yup in the code instead of Yup. Below is the code sample and it works perfectly :)

```
import * as Yup from "yup";

const formSchema = Yup.object().shape({
  email: Yup.string().required().email(),
  password: Yup.string().required().min(6),
});
```

Answer (score 0):

in my case I forgot to `export` validationSchema `function`, and access in other file which makes to cause `undefined` for `erros.userName`

Answer (score 0):

For me registering desired field helped:

```
{...register('birthDate')}
```