# Cannot find type definition file for 'yup'

Tags: typescript, yup, tsc

Im currently working on my backend project, which I wrote using **typescript** and nodejs.

Now, I wanted to implement some validation for my endpoints and I decided to use "*yup*".
I wrote my code and it hasn't shown any errors. But after compiling my project with `tsc` ,
it has shown this error:

```
error TS2688: Cannot find type definition file for 'yup'.
  The file is in the program because:
    Entry point for implicit type library 'yup'
```

Of course, I informed myself beforehand on the Internet what the error means. But after checking possible solutions, none of these worked.

Im using:

```
tsc: 4.1.2
yup: 0.32.0
@types/yup: 0.32.0 // as devDependecies
```

and my tsconfig.json looks like this:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./build",
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "typeRoots": ["./node_modules/@types", "./typings"]
  }
}
```

I hope somebody has any idea, what the problem could be. Thank you very much for your time :).

Comment: You shouldn't need to use `@types/yup`, as per the message on the npm package: [https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/yup](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/yup)
Is the problem specific to yup or do you also get it when importing another package?

Comment: Ensure that your TypeScript version is compatible with the version of '@types/yup' that you are using, you can check it in the 'yup' package documentation, you can try to delete the 'node_modules' and reinstalling it too

Comment: @colinD Its specific to yup. Also, when I remove @types/yup, I get tons of error message like: error TS2339: Property 'object' does not exist on type 'typeof import("yup")'

Comment: @BernardoAlmeida Reinstalled but still the same...

Comment: what command do you use?

Comment: yup also recently released a 1.0 version, which might be the reason. Did you try with `yup: 1.0` (and without `@types/yup`)?

Comment: @BernardoAlmeida rm package-lock.json -> rm node_modules -> npm install

Comment: @colinD After I just installed the new version, it gave me still the same erros like: TypeError: Cannot read property 'object' of undefined

Answer (score 0):

After several hours of searching, I found a Solution for my problem above:

```
// wrong
import Yup from 'yup';

// correct
import * as Yup from 'yup';
```

From this post: [Formik and Yup : TypeError: Cannot read property 'object' of undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50753832/formik-and-yup-typeerror-cannot-read-property-object-of-undefined)